# API de integração NFC-e (nota fiscal do consumidor eletrônica) com PHP

Tags: php, api

Alguém sabe de algum manual de integração da Nota Fiscal do Consumidor eletrônica para utilização do PHP? Estou desenvolvendo um sistema que contém controle de vendas, e necessitaria emitir uma NFC-e, porém não encontro em lugar algum nenhuma documentação falando a respeito.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A Fazenda não disponibiliza nenhum tutorial ou qualquer outra coisa com base em linguagem, apenas disponibiliza informações sobre os endereços de *webservice* na página [URL WebService](http://www.nfce.fazenda.sp.gov.br/NFCePortal/Paginas/URLWebServices.aspx).

A documentação e os Schemas XML pode ser encontrado na página [Arquivos Vigentes](http://www.nfce.fazenda.sp.gov.br/NFCePortal/Paginas/ArquivosVigentes.aspx).

Você apenas precisa "saber programar", que com essas informações você consegue utilizar o *webservice* em qualquer linguagem.

Para acessar os *webservices* você pode utilizar a biblioteca cURL do PHP:

- http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.curl.php
- http://imasters.com.br/artigo/4140/php/usando-a-biblioteca-curl-do-php/

Juntamente com uma biblioteca de XML:

- http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.simplexml.php
- http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.xml.php

Ou pode utilizar a [Biblioteca NFePHP](https://github.com/nfephp-org/nfephp) de terceiros, disponível no GitHub.

Answer (score 4):

Além da comunicação direta com a receita você pode utilizar APIs comerciais que eventualmente irão economizar seu tempo de desenvolvimento. Além da já apontada pelo KaduAmaral recomendo a API do Focus NFe (https://focusnfe.com.br/nfce-documentacao/) que possui exemplos prontos em PHP usando [PECL](https://focusnfe.com.br/api-documentacao/#exemplos-de-codigo-nfe-php-pecl) ou [CURL](https://focusnfe.com.br/api-documentacao/#exemplos-de-codigo-nfe-php-curl)

Uma opção intermediária seria gerar o arquivo no [formato do aplicativo da SEFAZ de SP](https://focusnfe.com.br/api-documentacao/#nfe-autorizacao-formatos) e utilizar o [emissor gratuito](http://www.emissornfe.fazenda.sp.gov.br/).

Trabalho na empresa que fornece a API citada acima e se você entender que este é o melhor caminho estou a disposição. Senão os dois caminhos apontados (NFe PHP e o que citei sobre o emissor gratuito) são ótimas opções.

Comment: Ricardo, você trabalha para essa empresa? Se for o caso, por favor deixe isso claro, ou sua resposta pode ser considerada spam. Obrigado.

Comment: Pronto @bfavaretto. Se você olhar eu nunca coloquei esta resposta em nenhuma outra pergunta, somente nesta em que ele pergunta claramente sobre APIs. Obrigado pela dica.

Comment: Melhorou bastante desta forma.